# "Are there...?" with and without the word "any"

Tags: grammar, questions, some-any

I am wondering about the usage of the word "any" with the construction "Are there...?".

Does it makes any difference if I ask

> Are there **any** books on the shelf?

or

> Are there books on the shelf?

I barely ever meet such question sentences without "any", so it sounds unusual to me, but I cannot find any rule that would say that one variant is more preferable to the other.

Comment: There is a similar and useful question here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/332502/are-there-with-and-without-the-word-any

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of it is that you would ask "Are there any books?" if you were hoping to find some, or if books were what you were interested in. Similarly - "Is there any milk in the fridge?"

You might ask "Are there books on the shelf, or just ornaments?" if you were interested in the way the shelf was being used.

Comment: The key article is Robin Lakoff's "Some reasons why there can't be any _some/any_ rule". _Any_ is of course a negative polarity item, but questions (particularly yes/no questions) are negative environments, so _any_ and other NPIs can occur. _Have you had any breakfast?_ and _Have you had some breakfast?_ ask the same question, but would be used for different reasons, having to do with the speaker's beliefs, presuppositions, desires, and currrent status. These will vary greatly from speaker to speaker, and from context to context, and can't be stated by rule.